# Refreshed Tor and lost log-in,home page and icons

Tags: windows, help, firefox

Clicked on "refresh tor" and lost my homepage and log-in.  still have utilities but browser is now Firefox. I clicked on  Utilities,  then Help (?), then troubleshooting information, On this page you can choose either " refresh tor" or "start in safe mode". After refreshing, Tor home page was gone , now Firefox. also shortcuts.  Still have utility but boot can't find proxy server.  Can I get my Tor back?

Comment: Can you clarify where or when "refresh tor" appears? I'm not familiar with it, or at least don't remember having seen it as a prompt.

Answer (score 3):

The Tor Browser Bundle is based on Firefox. The option you clicked is a Firefox feature that removes all of your add-ons and customizations, and resets everything to the default settings.

Since you can't download the TorButton and the TorLauncher add-ons, you'll have to download a fresh copy of TBB. Your homepage and shortcuts should be stored in a profile backup, which is usually saved to the Desktop. I'm not sure where TBB would save this, but I'm guessing it would be inside it's own folder somewhere.

Edit: I just tested it and confirmed that using Firefox Reset (or Refresh Tor as it's named here) **will** break the Tor browser, and you have to re-download the browser. Your bookmarks and other profile data is stored in the Tor Browser folder under Browser/Desktop/Old Firefox Data/profile.default.

Answer (score 1):

copy %userprofile%\desktop\Old Firefox Data\profile.default to %yourTORpath%\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser and rename to profile.default-1234567891011. Actually suffix is random, 
I guess, but I copied it from another profile in this directory. Then edit profile.ini in the same directory and put it as following: 
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default-1234567891011
IsRelative=1
Path=profile.default-1234567891011

And it works for me!